# c# - create and save an xml as UTF-8 (without BOM)

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I need to save an xml file in UTF-8 encoding but when i check in notepad++ the encoding is UTF-8 BOM. how do i forcefully make the encoding UTF-8. My code is below:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(tempPath, settings);
xdoc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: Why not save it with BOM?

Comment: @MindSwipe Like the duplicate explains, some parties are not happy with it.

Comment: Oh sorry guys i got it working...                                           settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);